# How to decrease the margin between elements in a form embed code

Tags: html, css, forms, embed, margin

I am trying to decrease the margins between elements in an embed code. I am linking to the site as well as attaching the code. You will see me explaining excatly what I am trying to do in the short screen share video right here. I have made some progress just by using inspect element and finding spots in the embed code that I can modify. But now I seem to have hit a wall and nothing that I change is doing the trick. Thank you all so much for your help! Here is the video and Embed code file down below. Stack overflow limits code to 30,000 characters so you will find a link to the full file down below.  Also here is the link to the landing page I am working on. http://unbouncepages.com/rvp-engagement-campaign-amp/

Also here is an image of the code I am looking at specifically.
[image: Photograph of Code in Sublime Text]

Check out this video: https://share.vidyard.com/watch/uQM5o7rjiqUmCATqGbfmdp?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s69zrbgrmg87n9q/Modified%20Lead%20Form%20Code?dl=0

Thanks again!

-Nathan

Answer (score 1):

I got you.

[image]

The margin you are looking at is on the label element inside of the li element. Override it with a custom style.

I added this in developer tools to test it, but you should add it inside of your code you have on sublime text then reload and test.

```
<style>
    .my-custom-style{
          margin: 0 !important;
     }
</style>
```

You will need the `!important` flag to override the other `!important` flags.
Place this directly above the label element like in the screenshot.
Then on the label element, make sure to add the class so it looks like this:

```
<label class="custom-form-label sort-element my-custom-style" ...></label>
```

(the `...` are there just to skip everything else for brevity. Don't paste that in).

Just make sure it is added as the last class to both elements that you want to override the margin on.

Also, another tip, if you really need to, you can try to add negative margin if you want to squish things a bit tighter.

```
 <style>
        .my-custom-style{
              margin-top: -5px !important;
              margin-bottom: -5px !important;
         }
 </style>
```

One last thought is it looks like you are using AMP, so adding the custom style like this might not validate correctly. There is a chance you will have to add the custom style to the styles in the header, where the other css is.

Comment: Hey man! Thank's a ton for your help here! I see how you did it in developer tools there but where would I place it in the actual embed code I have in sublime text? You'll see a screenshot of my code up above.